# Model Designer: Using Input in Advanced Python Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator

I am fairly familiar with QGIS's Model Designer, but only have a basic grasp of Python currently.  Due to a more complex requirement, I have needed to use the Advanced Field Calculator for some processing, and have been able to write what I require apart from one thing.

How can I access the data from one of the Inputs?

For example I have a Number type Input name StartKP.  If using the regular field calculator this would be accessed in the formula using just @StartKP but this does not work in the APFC (nor does any of the other dozens of syntax I've tried).